# Magento call event after import product

Tags: magento

I want to know which event will fire after product import action complete.I want to setup some logic after product import done from admin side in Magento. I have tried this **catalog_product_import_finish_before** but its not working in my case, I want to add my logic after product import work finish.

Is there any way to do this in Magento 1.9?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see a list of events in your system do a grep on the *app* folder for this term: `protected $_eventPrefix`. The closest I could get to your event was in `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php` file. Where event prefix is defined as:

```
protected $_eventPrefix = 'catalog_product_import';
```

You will need to extend this class and add your dispatch in it ! Plus I'm not sure if `finish` is used in Magento dynamic events. You might prefer to use `save_row` instead? [This](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-event-driven-programming-tips-tricks/) article might help you (search for dynamic events).

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not sure how you import your products, here is a generic way to find one.

If you open up app/Mage.php, look for the function dispatchEvent(). This function dispatches all the events in Magento. If you add a logging call somewhere in that function, you can log all events being fired and thus find the event you need.

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    Mage::log($name,null,'events.log');
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

The data will show up in var/log/events.log. Be sure to have logging enabled. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the only event dispatched in `ImportExport` module. So if this one is not doing it for you, then you could create your module (if not already done) and rewrite `startAction()` from `Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ImportController` and add your logic where you need in that method.

Here is how this can be done (supposing module is Mycompany_ImportExport)  :
In your module's `etc/config.xml` add following tags in config section to create controller rewrite :

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Mycompany_ImportExport before="Mage_ImportExport">Mycompany_ImportExport_Adminhtml
                    </Mycompany_ImportExport>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Then create folder `Mycompany/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml` and create a file `ImportController.php`.

Finally add:

```
require_once 'Mage/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml/ImportController.php';

class Mycompany_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ImportController extends Mage_ImportExport_Adminhtml_ImportController
{
    public function startAction()
    {
        // duplicate code from original and add logic here
    }
}
```